# CSS/js Flip Cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a card cover and back of the card. How can I flip my card from cover to back by the click on the button, [like this](http://css3playground.com/3d-flip-cards/)?

[Here is demo](http://jsbin.com/gecobovize/1/)

Comment: You haven't given any information beyond the links - one of which is your "demo" which seems totally unrelated. Provide some code to show what you've tried please.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need

**html**

```
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; } .flip3D > .front{ position:absolute; -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); background:#FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden; transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s; transition: transform .5s linear 0s; } .flip3D > .back{ position:absolute; -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg ); transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg ); background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden; transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s; transition: transform .5s linear 0s; } .flip3D:hover > .front{ -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg ); transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg ); } .flip3D:hover > .back{ -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/9444/